# How to enable debug mode of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl

Tags: java, xml, java-8, xerces

I got a weird XML parsing error all of a sudden and would like to go to the bottom of it, real time debugging a SAX parser doesn't seem to work out.

I noticed in this code base of `XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl` there'r some flags that enabled debugging, however they are static final default to false:
[image: XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl]

Anyone knows if these can be turned on by some mechanism?
Is there a source repo I can rebuild into maven artifact? I tried to copy these out from `java/8.0.242-amzn/jre/lib/rt.jar` and rebuilt them but it only bring up a chain of other missing classes that never end.

Comment: XY-Problem.   Just post a [mcve] that includes your XML, code, and error message so that we could help with the actual issue.